# Gvim fails to open: E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

I'm new to Linux, and I just installed Linuz Mint under VMware Player. I'm trying to learn how to program, and I was trying Gvim (Vim's GUI).

I installed Vim using `sudo apt-get install vim` and tried to run Gvim by `vim first.c -g`
 but get the error message:

```
E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: As much as I like Vim I can't recommend anybody to learn programming *and* Vim at the same time. Learn programming first with a "simple" IDE/editor *then*, if you are still curious, learn Vim.

Comment: @romainl I already know C programing. My target platform is now for Unix so that's why I installed Linux. Do you recommend Vim as an editor?

Comment: Vim is the most awesome text editor ever but that awesomeness comes at a price: it can take a while to become efficient. That time is probably more wisely spent working on more immediately rewarding things. It's up to you to set your priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install another package for GVIM; that'll also get you the `gvim` command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

For centos refer to the link: http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/03/solving-e25-gui-cannot-be-used-not.html. Basically, you need to install `vim-enhanced` and `vim-X11` as well.

```
yum install vim-enhanced # To install the fuller package of vim
yum install vim-X11 # To installed the equivalent of gvim
```